# C++ Template error: " "Unknown Template Name " in Xcode

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, hierarchy

I am working on a code with this class template hierarchy:

```
template<class T>
class function{
protected:
    T *f;
    int N0, N;
public:
    T& operator[](int i) {Assert(i<N,"Out of range in function[]"); return f[i];}
    const T& operator[](int i) const {Assert(i<N,"Out of range in function[]"); return f[i];}
    const T& last() const {return f[N-1];}
    int size() const { return N;}
    int fullsize() const { return N0;}
    function& operator+=(const function& m);
    function& operator*=(const T& m);
    T* MemPt(){return f;}
    const T* MemPt() const{return f;}
    function& operator=(const T& c);
protected:
    function() : f(NULL), N0(0), N(0) {};
    explicit function(int N_) : N0(N_), N(N_) {};
    ~function(){};
    function(const function&){};
    template<class U> friend class function2D;
    template <class U> friend U scalar_product(const function<U>& f1, const function<U>& f2);
};

//******************************************************************//
// One dimensional functions derived from function<T>. It has it's  //
// own constructors and destructors.                    //
//******************************************************************//
template <class T>
class function1D : public function<T>{   //HERE IS THE ERROR 
public:
    function1D(){};
    explicit function1D(int N_);
    ~function1D();
    function1D(const function1D& m);
    void resize(int N_);
    function1D& operator=(const function1D& m);
    function1D& operator=(const T& c) {function<T>::operator=(c); return *this;}
    void Product(const function2D<T>& A, const function<T>& x, double alpha=1., double beta=0.);
};
```

I receive this error at the line specified by "HERE IS THE ERROR"

Error: "Unknown Template Name 'function'

I am totally confused as this seems just a simple inheritance !

I am using this C++ code in Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: Is `function` directly visible to `function1D` or is it stuffed in a different namespace or header file that's not included?

Comment: The only error I get pasting this into a simple Xcode 5.1.1 project source .cpp file is about `const function2D<T>& A` denoting an undefined template name (which is correct, since you didn't provide us that template).

Comment: Are you saying `using namespace std;` anywhere? In such a case, `function` would be conflicting with `std::function`.

Comment: Are these declarations in the same file?

Comment: [**See it work**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc0e298091d3d860), then [**see it fail**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b82177eae18156f). One of these things is not like the other...

Comment: @WhozCraig That's an unusually bad error message for clang. Seems specific to the case when an ambiguous template used as a base class. In other situations it clearly says `reference to 'function' is ambiguous`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Yes they are in the same file

Comment: @iavr Nowhere in the scope I used namespace std

Comment: @Aug You may have included some file that did it. Run `clang++ -E ...` and grep the result for `using namespace std` or perhaps `using std::function`.